# write a normal js object (not native to php) to local file with php

Tags: javascript, php

I have an object file in memory to which I used javascript push to add new items. Can I use the updated active memory version to write to a local disk file with php? It will be difficult since the string "var members =" disqualifies it as a legitimate php array.

```
<script>
var members = [ 
{ "Class": "B", "Rating": "1776", "ID": "12537964", "Name": "Smith, John", "Expires": "2018.10.18" }, 
{ "Class": "C", "Rating": "1500", "ID": "12210580", "Name": "Jones, Jim", "Expires": "2019.01.12" }, 
{ "Class": "B", "Rating": "1759", "ID": "10117780", "Name": "Williams, Paula", "Expires": "2018.09.12" }
]
</script>
```

Comment: This is too hacky, use plain JSON, that's the proper way. You're complicating things for yourself

Comment: I can't ... I use the variable "members" for dozens of modules. Removing  "var members =" will screw everything up.

Answer (score 0):

```
var membersJson = JSON.stringify(members);
```

Write this value to disk with PHP. This way you don't change your members var at all.

Comment: You can't exchange data from javascript to php. AFAIK. An object in js, even in memory, can't be accessed in php.

Comment: your could do a post xmlhttprequest posting the memberJson var as data to PHP and write to file.